# using multiple themes for multiple products types

Tags: theme

I am not a professional
I need to make business directories eg car dealers, restaurants and shops in the main page
From the main page when enter category i need to set different themes since each category have a different requirements 
also I need a search engine for each category 
please clarify for me how since I am searching for answer for weeks
thank you for your help

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 1 & Magento 2 you can use the Design settings on the categories and products to set different themes and updates for that categories and products.

Example for the category (Magento 2):

[image: Category in magento 2 example]

Comment: so no matter the number of themes installed I can choose between them for specific page :)

Comment: @johnsmith If my answer is helpful, please, accept it.